# Running error with basic react-native project

Tags: android, react-native

I'm on linux (ubuntu) and i ran `npx react-native start` and `npx react-native run-android` after creating the project with `npx react-native init project-name` and I'm using my phone to run the app, but when I open it I get this page https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lAk1.jpg and then a white page, how do I get it to work?

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well. Posts in which required text content is only present in images are likely to be closed as lacking enough details.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to react-native and faced same error with physical device.
It was resolved after few trials, I disconnected my device and put it **again in developer mode** and connected it. I was using expo so i cleared expo cache.